# Can you write your own review on a resort in Sims 3 Island Paradise?

Tags: the-sims-3, the-sims

I run my own resort in the *Sims 3 Island Paradise* expansion. And I must admit, the reviews really help my resort mold into the resort it is.

Anyway, the people or sims that submit these reviews seem like actual players, according to their name tags (like Like Dan599) you see at the side of the review.

So I was wondering if I could write my own review for a resort (besides my own resort).

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot. It is a generated review.